# When a web server returns a JPEG image (mime type image/jpeg), how is that encoded?

Tags: http, mime-types

If you make an HTTP request to a web server, and it returns a response of type image/jpeg, how is the binary data actually encoded? Is it the original byte-level content of the image that goes across the wire, or some character-based representation of it (e.g. base64)?

Comment: Even character based data (HTML, CSS, JS, etc) is transferred as bytes. Anything else doesn't computers and networking understand anyway.

Comment: We share the same question. I think we both **unnecessarily** distinguish between the bytes of a piece of text and bytes of an image. At the binary level, they are nothing but the same bits. My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20086460/what-does-http-download-exactly-mean

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The encoded transfered data is specified by the `Content-Encoding` HTTP response header (see HTTP 1.1 specifications in [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) section 14.11 and 3.5). If present, it can be either `gzip`, `compress`, or `deflate` compressed data (no others are defined in HTTP 1.1). If not, the data is in original encoding based on the `Content-Type` HTTP response header (the MIME type). The `Content-Encoding` is determined by the `Accept-Encoding` HTTP request header value and whether the web server support requested encoding.

In your case, if the `Content-Encoding` HTTP response header is absent, the data is exactly the same as the file contents. Otherwise, it's compressed with the specified encoding. e.g.: *GZip* or *Deflate*.

Comment: Generally speaking, a well-configured web server will not compress jpgs (though it's certainly possible).  (Unless I'm missing something?)

Comment: The final decision will always be on the web server, whether it's for optimization or because the requested encoding isn't supported (i.e.: asking for *Base64* on a HTML file). While an `Accept-Encoding` header may state to accept `deflate` and others as unacceptable (i.e.: `deflate;q=1, *;q=0`), most servers won't return HTTP code 406 and return the data unencoded. See section 14.3 note and section 3.9. Test that request with http://alternativeto.net/about.

Comment: I think you're agreeing with what I said--but it's not entirely clear to me.  In any event, thanks for the details.

Answer (score 2):

The original bytes are sent across the wire.

(With a bit of setup, you can confirm this with Wireshark, tcp_dump et al.)

Note that most servers are configured *not* to compress JPEGs, but that text data is generally sent compressed.

Comment: Yeah, and it wouldn't make much sense to compress JPEG files because they already pass an entropy compression stage, you won't go any further with zipping ^^

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, it's not "straight through".

Apart from adding the MIME header, the webserver appears to strip out all the jpeg markers (0xFF, 0xNN) but leaves the rest intact.  This seems strange as I don't know how the web browser is then recognising the start of the image frame.

I found this out by writing my own simple webserver in an embedded system - I thought I'd only need to add the MIME header and send the rest of the jfif-jpeg file untouched, but the browser says "the image cannot be displayed because it contains errors"!

here's the start of the original jpeg/jfif in hex

ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00

[SOI][APP0][length]J  F  I  F NULL

As per the spec.

The received file contains this, after the header:

0d 0a 0d 0a 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00

The first 4 bytes are cr/lf/cr/lf at the end of the header, then NO markers, but it does contain the data field.  The same thing is repeated for the other markers e.g. start of frame.

Strange huh?  I don't think it's an mime encoding issue, as the rest of the data looks intact - including FFs in the data etc.

Anyone know what's going on here?
PS to look closer, just request a .jpg from any website using putty or similar and save what you get, and compare it to the original, or even the saved-as version.

Comment: That would be a broken server.

Comment: I have also written my own web server.  Mine is also not working.  I tried the fix you mentioned above with no luck.  However I am wondering if you found that more blank lines were needed between the pic and the header.  I am going to see if changing that data will help.